# Can the performance of this SQL inner join be improved?

Tags: python, sql, performance, sqlite

I am using python and `sqllite3` and I was wondering if the performance of this query can be improved?

`main` table with ~100,000 rows

```
    0   1   2   3   4   Amount
0   0   9   12  6   60  40800.0
1   0   9   12  6   61  40100.0
2   0   9   12  6   65  39900.0
3   0   9   12  6   74  40300.0
4   0   9   12  7   60  40600.0
```

`util` table ~75,000 rows

```
    0   1   2   Amount
0   78  75  65  9900.0
1   80  75  65  9900.0
2   80  72  65  10000.0
3   78  72  65  10000.0
4   79  75  65  10000.0
```

The query currently gets the Cartesian product of the two tables where the sum of the amount is between 49,700 and 50,000 and gets the first 200,000 matches if my understanding is correct.

```
con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
df.to_sql(name='main', con=con)
df1.to_sql(name='util', con=con)

query = '''
SELECT *
FROM main AS m
INNER JOIN
util AS u
ON
  50000 >= m.Amount + u.Amount
AND
  49700 <= m.Amount + u.Amount
LIMIT
  200000;
'''
final_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con)
```

Comment: Please explain the query, possibly by adding sample data.  Note that using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is fairly meaningless.

Comment: Updated the explination @TimBiegeleisen, I was under the impression that using `LIMIT` would get the first 200,000 matches since there are plenty of possible matches and this would take much longer.

Comment: His point was that without ORDER BY, you don't know _which_ 200,000 matches are being returned. It could be the first 200k, the last 200k, or 200k records randomly from the results.

Comment: It may be helpful to prepend the query with "EXPLAIN". Instead of executing the query it returns a table with the generated [bytecode](https://sqlite.org/opcode.html) for executing the query. This may allow a better guess if and how optimization is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not matching on a column value, but **on the expression `m.Amount + u.Amount`**, it has to be **computed for every possible combination of rows** between the two tables (100k * 75k = 7500mil or 7.5 billion combos). What you've effectively got is a CROSS JOIN since you're not matching on any column between the two tables.

**1.** You can make sure the expression is evaluated only once rather than for each part of the AND clause `50000 >= m.Amount + u.Amount` & `49700 <= m.Amount + u.Amount` by using the `BETWEEN` operator. I would just the standard 'from table1, table2' with `WHERE` for clarity:

```sql
SELECT * FROM main AS m
INNER JOIN
util AS u
ON
  m.Amount + u.Amount BETWEEN 49700 AND 50000
;
```

**2.** You'll have to use other methods to reduce the number of rows that are checked. For example, when `Amount` for either tables is more than 50,000 it can't be a match, so it gets exclude earlier in the verification and saves time by not computing `m.Amount + u.Amount` even once:

```sql
SELECT * FROM main AS m, util AS u
WHERE
  m.Amount <= 50000
AND
  u.Amount <= 50000
AND
  m.Amount + u.Amount BETWEEN 49700 AND 50000
;
```

If the amounts cannot be 0, then change the `<= 50000` to `< 50000`.

**3.** You can do other things like find the minimum Amount in each table and then make sure that the other table's Amount is less than `50000 - that first min amt`.

**4.** Using the "sum of 2 numbers" problem, you can do a one-time calculation of a minimum match Amt and max match Amt (add two new columns) for one of the tables and then use the BETWEEN check using the Amt from the other table. It still needs to do a cross join but the cpu-time to evaluate each match is reduced.

```sql
ALTER TABLE main ADD COLUMN min_match INT default 0;
ALTER TABLE main ADD COLUMN max_match INT default 0;
UPDATE main SET min_match = 49700 - Amount,
                max_match = 50000 - Amount;

SELECT * FROM main AS m, util AS u
WHERE
  u.Amount BETWEEN m.min_match AND m.max_match
;
```